# MongoDB: two nodes & primary election

Tags: replication, mongodb

According to Mongo documentation in order to safely deploy a replication set, you need at least two active and one arbiter because election of the a primary needs the majorities of the votes.

Let's say I'm able to have three machines, therefore deploy three full-blown mongo instances, no arbiter.

If the elected primary fails I end up with TWO nodes, where both of them has the same "power" level: for me this seems to be the must-aviod situation described at the deploy.

Can someone unfold why is it not a problem to elect a primary in this situation when it is if the initial setup is the same?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Electing a primary in a two node set isn't a problem as long as both nodes are available. The rule is that the majority of the set needs to be up to successfully elect a primary.

In a two node set:

- If both nodes are up, it can elect a primary
- If only one node is up, it cannot see a majority and will remain read only

In a three node set:

- If three nodes are up, one can become primary
- If two nodes are up, one can become primary
- If only one node is up, it's read only

A two node + arbiter set behaves just like a three node set, so if any one node (including the arbiter) fails, it can elect a primary.

It's important to realize that a set with only two voting nodes is running without write redundancy. You wouldn't want to create a set that always runs like that (hence, the arbiter), and you also want to recover a third node as soon as practically possible in the event of an outage.

Comment: This is OK, and thank you for the explanation, but I still don't have an answer why is it not a problem to elect from two nodes when one fails in a three-node setup and is when I do a two-node setup :)

Comment: actually, it does answer the question - 2/3 = majority, 2/2 = majority.  The difference is that in a 3 node set if you lose a node you still have a fully functioning primary and a secondary, in a 2 node set if you lose a single node you are read only (no primary).  You can run with 2 nodes, it just doesn't get you anything from a redundancy perspective - in fact you have made your system more likely to fail.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but in case anyone is still confused, in a 3-node set, if you lose a node, it doesn't become a 2-node set.  It's still a 3-node set of which 2/3 (more than half) are operational.  In a 2-node set, if one goes down, it's a 2-node set with 1/2 operational (not a majority).  It took me a while to understand that it's not the fact that there are 2 nodes up, it's the fact that it's 2/3 vs 2/2.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you'd have hopefully set [priorities](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#local.system.replset.members%5Bn%5D.priority) on your nodes.

In testing, there seem to be other factors which are not as transparent, I have tested a 3 nodes replication set, and upon stepping down (and shutting down the nodes also), the nodes tend to take turns, first 1, then 2 then 3.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB replica sets use a basic leader election algorithm.  If you have 3 nodes then you if you have atleast two functional nodes then you have a "quorum" and the cluster continues to operate fine. If you loose two nodes then you dont have "quorum" and leader election cannot proceed and the surviving replica is a in a read only state.